# How to register custormEntityInterceptor to multiple datasources in grails?

Tags: grails

I have an entity interceptor defined in resources.groovy to manipulate SQL (onPrepareStatement()), which is applying on default datasource(DB2), but not other datasource(H2 DB) defined in datasource.groovy. Can you please help how to configure interceptor to apply it for all datasources?

```
Resources.groovy:
 beans = {
  ...
  entityInterceptor(com.XXX.grendel.util.Db2IsolationLevelInterceptor)
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is named 'myds' then:

```
entityInterceptor_myds(com.XXX.grendel.util.Db2IsolationLevelInterceptor)
```

will apply the interceptor to myds.